# How do I get the coordinates for the top right corner of a UIImageView after it's been rotated?

Tags: iphone, transform, rotation, trigonometry

How would I go about getting the coordinate for the top right corner of a uiimageview after it's been rotated?

Comment: Can you plz elaborate what you want to achieve ?

Comment: After a UIImageView is rotated I would I like to the get coordinates of the top right corner for that image view

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do what I am doing except it is not exactly the complete solution to the QUESTION it is the solution to my problem. All I had to do was the image view I wanted on the top right corner of the image view being rotated had to be added as a subview of the image rotated and moved by an offset to be at the corner.